# Setting the default java desktop app icon for all sub-frames?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, icons, desktop-application

I've managed to replace the java coffee cup in the corner with my own icon, however my application has about 13 frames, and when I manually call the icon like I did on my mainframe it says cannot find symbol getframe().

Any idea how to set the default icon to the icon the main frame has? I used this code to apply my icon to the main frame:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("calculatormedii/resources/CMed1.png");
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image img = kit.createImage(url);
        getFrame().setIconImage(img);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"sub frames" should be a JDialog and not a JFrame. The dialog will inherit the icon automatically as long as you specify the frame as the parent of the dialog in the constructor.

Comment: But I already have some jFrames which are implemented. Is there a way to convert them to jDialogs or manually add the icon to each?

Comment: Change JFrame to JDialog. You add components to a dialog the same way you do to a frame. So the main difference is the constructor used when creating the dialog as I suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

1. as I know not possible to easilly change Java Cup Icon for containers built from Java Desktop Aplication
2. Java Desktop Aplication is old Framework based on Swing, but lots of methods are protected and not accesible from outside
3. since (at first sight) looks like as very confortable just drad & drop pre_defined jComponents from palette, but change part of basic methods not easy job,
4. Java Desktop Aplication is old Framework and is depreciated a few years
5. use standard Swing JComponent, then you can't find any limits

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("calculatormedii/resources/CMed1.png");
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image img = kit.createImage(url);

        Frame[] frames = JFrame.getFrames();
        for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
            frames[i].setIconImage(img);
        }
```